# Find a closed form for the power series $f_p(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n^p}{n!}x^n$

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

I have come across a power series as follows,
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n^p}{n!}x^n.
\end{equation}
It shows that for some small $p$ values, we can derive simple closed forms:

$p=1: f(x)=e^xx$;

$p=2: f(x)=e^x(x+x^2)$;

$p=3: f(x)=e^x(x+3x^2+x^3)$;

$p=4: f(x)=e^x(x+7x^2+6x^3+x^4)$;

...

Is it possible to derive a closed-form for this power series for general $p$?

Comment: $$f(x)=e^xT_p(x)$$where $T$ is a [Touchard polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touchard_polynomials). Also see [Bell numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number#Moments_of_probability_distributions) and [Dobinski's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dobinski%27s_formula).

Comment: The underlying recursion is $$f_{p+1}(x)=xf'_p(x)\qquad f_0(x)=e^x$$ for every $p\geqslant0$ hence $$f_p(x)=e^xg_p(x)$$ with $$g_{p+1}(x)=x(g_p(x)+g'_p(x))\qquad g_0(x)=1$$ which shows that each $g_p(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $p$. For more details, see the links in @SimplyBeautifulArt's comment.

Comment: @Did there should not have a number_of_characters_bound specially for you in the comment section!

Comment: @Did you may be interested in the result I derived below.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Interesting, although one might wish to debate the validity of your "easy" at the end when $p$ is large... :-)

Answer (score 3):

I recently stumbled upon a fairly nifty identity.

> $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k\frac{x^k}{k!}=e^x\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^k(-1)^{k-m}a_m\frac{x^k}{k!}$$

Proof:

$$f(x):=e^{-x}\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k\frac{x^k}{k!}\\\begin{align}f^{(n)}(x)&=\sum_{m=0}^n\binom nm(-1)^{n-m}e^{-x}\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{k+m}\frac{x^k}{k!}\tag{Leibniz}\\f(x)&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty f^{(k)}(0)\frac{x^k}{k!}\\&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^k\binom kn(-1)^{k-n}a_n\frac{x^k}{k!}\end{align}$$

Where we used [general Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule) to differentiate.

Applying this here we get a finite sum nicely.

> $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty k^p\frac{x^k}{k!}=e^x\sum_{k=0}^p\sum_{n=0}^k\binom kn(-1)^{k-n}n^p\frac{x^k}{k!}$$

Which makes it easy to compute the coefficients of the polynomial. In fact, the above is a [Touchard polynomial](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touchard_polynomials). See also: [bell numbers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number#Moments_of_probability_distributions) and [Dobinski's formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dobi%C5%84ski%27s_formula).